# update data in database with specific condition in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to update list of data that is foreignkey in another table.

Scenario:

I have class A:

```
public class A{
    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "A", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> b;
}
```

i have also another class B:

```
public class B  {
    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    private A a;
}
```

My goal is: to update list of b in perfect way.

Example:

i have this id list for table B :

| id | name | a_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | n1 | 1 |
| 2 | n2 | 1 |
| 3 | n3 | 1 |
| 4 | n4 | 2 |
| 5 | n5 | 1 |
| 6 | n6 | 3 |

I have this list to update :

```
[n3,n9,n2,n7,n8]
```

this list must be updated for a_id = 1 so in this case i have 2 things to do:

```
first : adding n7, n8, n9 (with a_id = 1)
second: remove n1, n5 (because they are not included in the list above)
```

My expected output :

| id | name | a_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | n2 | 1 |
| 3 | n3 | 1 |
| 4 | n4 | 2 |
| 6 | n6 | 3 |
| 7 | n7 | 1 |
| 8 | n8 | 1 |
| 9 | n9 | 1 |

How can we achieve this result in the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following mapping and just merge/save the `A` entity, and Hibernate will take care of removing/persisting/updating.

```java
public class A {
    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    private List<B> b;
}

public class B {
    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
}
```

If you want to keep the `a` association in `B`, then you will have to do the persist/update/remove manually, by calling `EntityManager.persist`/`EntityManager.merge`/`EntityManager.remove` respectively for the various `B` entities.